# how to convert a parameter to a string without any error

Tags: javascript, string, parameters

i have a small function that alerts the name of any person but i want that only a name should be passes as a parameter not a string... you will understand from the following code for what i am asking for...

```
var _s  = function(name){
    return String(name);
}
```

so when i call this function and write my name `anni` then i must not write`"anni"` i should simply type `anni` as a parameter. i tried many methods and the error which accompanied them are written as comment:

```
var _s  = function(string(name)){
    alert(String(name));
} // unexpected token (
```

another try

```
var _s  = function( function n(name){return string(name)} ){
    alert(n());
}// unexpected token function
```

another...

```
var _s  = function(var x =  name.tostring ){
    alert(String(x));
}// unexpected token var
```

now to solve this...

i also thinked first to replace the name with numbers then again with letters but the same thing was there to dealt with...

i searched on internet but the answers were coming, they were different... not related with this topic... so i finally asked here.

thanks for every suggestion and answers!

Comment: and i also dont want first to define a variable for it

Comment: What are you actually trying to do (as I think your example is confusing) are you trying to call a function by name from another function? Where do you expect to pass a variable into this if you haven't declared it already? i.e. if i type `var _s  = function(anni){` <- where is anni coming from and if you are typing it in why do you need a function for it?

Comment: are you trying to return the name of all variables a function accepts? i.e. function thisOne(cheese, potato) would alert "cheese" and "potato"??

Comment: yes... i want this only

Comment: ok so are you trying to pass in another function to get the names of the variables it accepts or just the current function? i.e. pass in my example above to another function -> findMyVars(thisOne); ????? otherwise I don't see the point!